# ember-simple-auth-devise not authenticating

Tags: ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I have an Ember CLI front-end app, and a Rails app using Devise for authentication. I thought I had things set up correctly, but I am running into a few problems.

1) After submitting the login form, I do not get re-directed. If I manually click a link that is behind authentication, it sees I'm authenticated.

2) After reloading the page, the session info in local storage doesn't persist.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) it by defaults redirect to index route after login, stick a debugger in the beforeModel hook of the index route and verify this

2) something like this in your config/environment.js, but since your using the devise plugin and not your own custom authorizer not 100% sure

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  localStorageKey: 'my-app-session',
  store: 'simple-auth-session-store:local-storage',
  authorizer: 'authorizer:devise'
};
```

it's sort of vague questions though, need more code and info if your using tokens or cookies, etc?

Comment: Hi Flylib,

Sorry, I knew I probably should have provided more info but wasn't sure what would be relevant.

It looks like it was a rails-csrf library thing. Removing that fixed it.

I still lose the session though when I reload the page. It doesn't persist in local storage.

Comment: Happens in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. This is the contents of local storage after logging in: {"authenticator":"simple-auth-authenticator:devise","sessions":[["trainer_token","FZHxDS_CB-VN1uc74NNo"],["trainer_email”,”**********@gmail.com"]]}

Comment: try sticking that code above in your environment/config.js if your using ember-cli

Comment: try this ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
  resourceName: 'trainer'
};

Comment: your issue seems to be you have trainer as the key instead of user, read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215010/ember-simple-auth-session-lost-on-refresh and here https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/tree/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise#server-side-setup

Comment: Ahhh I figured it out. It looks like because I am using activemodel serializers in my rails app, it was including the root(in this case sessions: because the response was being served from sessions controller).

I told it to not use ActiveModel Serializers,  render json: data, status: 201, serializer: nil

That did the trick!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh I figured it out. It looks like because I am using activemodel serializers in my rails app, it was including the root(in this case sessions: because the response was being served from sessions controller). I told it to not use ActiveModel Serializers, render json: data, status: 201, serializer: nil That did the trick! I'm guessing AMS and custom resource names do not play well together.